# ASP.Net jquery TextBox Event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, textbox, asp.net-ajax

Can I call textbox changed event as text changing using jquery in asp.net?
So, I want the action to be done while the user is entering the number.

**Default.aspx**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCount" CssClass="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" OnTextChanged="OnTextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblTotal" CssClass="price" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void txtIskontoTutari_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double price1=double.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
    double count=double.Parse(txtCount.Text);
    double total=0;
    total=price1*count;
    lblTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##0.00}", total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be the solution:

You have do take the ID Attribute of your asp tag.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#txtPrice').change(function(){
      $(this).....
    }
});
```